# Login Loop in Recovery Mode

Tags: login

I am suddenly experiencing the following situation on a  Ubuntu 16.04 installation, which has worked fine for many months.

1. Normal reboot get stucks at a purple screen (without any logos)
2. Recovery Mode gets to the login screen but then loops indefinitely (after entering user password, I have to re-enter it and so on)
3. ttys (entering bash mode with ctrl+alt+f2) work on recovery mode, so I can login from there, if I need to run commands.

I suppose that problems 1 and 2 are related, but I don't know why this happened. What is the problem and what approach do I need to solve it?

edit: I finally managed to login with recovery mode, by running  `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` from tty2, which I guess corrected my nvidia drivers. But normal boot does not work, it get stuck on the purple screen.

edit2: I tried to clean install Ubuntu 20.04, but it get's stuck on the 3rd step (where you choose updates,third party software etc)

Comment: What changes were made in your system immediately before the problem happened? Updates installed, files modified or deleted?

Comment: hello, no changes were made! Just normal browsing / word processing the day before.